# how to add java classpath in netbeans

Tags: java, classpath

I'm writing a java program in netbeans. But I need to add a classpath something.jar.
In netbeans how can I do that?
I compile with command:

```
java -classpath .:something.jar MyCode.java
```

Comment: Actuly I solved the issue some minutes after this post. I forgot to mention here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NetBeans Project Properties Window, you click Libraries in the left panel, and in the right panel are 4 categories of classpath you can configure. Take a look at this article, it's back from 2006, but this part of Netbeans remained pretty much the same: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps with image description :)

[How to add jar file in Netbeans](http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/)

Let me know if you need something else...

Good Luck!!!

Comment: External linking is discouraged. Please include the relevant content in your answer.