# How do I add the jgrapht library to my system?

Tags: compilation, classpath, java, jgrapht

This is probably a silly question, but how or where do I add jgrapht so my java compiler in terminal will include it? I've got the `.jar` file but don't know where to put it.

I'm using Mac OS X ML and Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an external Java library you need to add it to your classpath. The Java documentation has some great information on [how to set it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html).

Assuming you're using the `javac` compiler, you'll use a command similar to:

> `javac -classpath` *path to jgrapht jar file* `...` `other options and files here ...`

See also: [Compiling Java](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/tcljava98/notes/compiling.html)

You specifiacally mention Netbeans, so you'll also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139714/how-to-add-java-classpath-in-netbeans), and this [blog post](http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/).

I hope this helps! :)