# No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I'm getting a message that:***"No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"*** When I run the jar file in dist folder.

I'm using Netbeans,what's confusing me is the fact that,when I execute the program from inside  Netbeans ,it works perfectly.

```
  try {
       Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
       //**please note that I also tried "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",but same result**
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
   }
```

And my connection string is:"jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"

Comment: None of the dozens of questions already on SO that cover this helped?

Comment: add the driver class jar file to the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the appropriate [jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), and add it to your class path. Then you can use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                               "user=monty&password=greatsqldb");
```

But you do not use `Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");`.

Comment: How do I add it to the classpath?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9139752/2970947

Comment: or http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/

Comment: And under most circumstances, you don't need to use `Class.forName` anymore.