# Find classpath in NetBeans 8.0.2?

Tags: java, path, classpath, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 editor. How do I find the classpath of a specific project? And how do I setup a new classpath for a specific project?

Comment: The classpath is kind of setup dynamically by netbeans.  Depending on the type of project you've created, you can add libraries (both class files and jar files), projects and/or other sources.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have error `classnotfoundexception` and want to fix it... so want to specify the correct path.

Comment: You need to identify the source the class and either add it through the "library" node or as an additional `src` (if it's source code not in another Netbeans project) via the project properties

Comment: sorry not understand, please tell me what to do exactly ? what steps should i make in netbeans ??

Comment: It depends, is the class you're trying to resolve a `.java` file, `.class` file or contained within a `.jar` file or a within another netbeans project?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139714/how-to-add-java-classpath-in-netbeans) or [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html) will help

Comment: Still not understand, so let me clarify more.... i have some classes in a specific package ... ok ... when i run my project it throws the error ... but when i move these classes to the default package it works good ... can you help me please in this ?? @MadProgrammer

Comment: That sounds like you did put the appropriate `package` declarations within you class/source files

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean that classes in the package are not related to each other ..... no i don't think that .... all my classes in the same package have association relationship between each other.

Comment: No, I mean that they should 1- be in a directory which is named exactly like the `package` name and 2- the first lines should have a `package` declaration stating the package that they are in

Comment: Ok i understand you, all you talking about is satisfied. and same problem exists